# JQuery validation using HTML 5, but shouldn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, validation

I have implemented in project jQuery Validation. I have also enable novalidate on html. jQuery Validation works, because when I comment validate() - validation is disabled, but I don't know why, validation is using not mine rules, but rules from HTML. In this example validation asking about 3 signs on input, not 6 as on jQuery rule. After delete html tags regarding validation, validation stopped.

I want to use only jQuery validation, but html makes it imposible. Help, please :)

```
    $('#PersonForm').validate({
        rules: {
              person_first_name: {required: true, minlength: 6},
         },
         messages: {
              person_first_name: 'some message'
         }
   });
```

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" minlength="3" maxlength="150" id="person_first_name" name="person_first_name" placeholder="{t('Name')}*"
```

Comment: remove `required="required"` from the tag

Comment: After remove required="required" from html tag, jQuery validation not work.

Comment: Why not update HTML attributes to match your jQuery validation? `minlength="6"`, etc?

Comment: Because I wanted to use personalized error messages. Otherwise it is strange, why jquery vaidation is using parameters from validate from html.

Comment: *Because I wanted to use personalized error messages* - that's what `messages` is for in jQuery validation? *why jquery vaidation is using parameters from validate from html* - is it really? Isn't it just the browser? What do you see, **exactly**?

Comment: 'some message' here it is just example of course. Browser shouldn't validate this form because I include novalidate="novalidate" on html form tag. As I said, when I disable jquery validateion - form is sending without any validation. But when I enable jQuery validation, it is using parameters from html (for example minlength="3", but not 6 as on jQuery.